# Display field choice as part of model string name

Tags: django

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices), what if I had

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
            return "%s [%s]" % (self.name, self.gender)
```

What if I wanted the __str definition to display as the full name (Male or Female) for self.gender instead of M or F?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use `get_gender_display()`:

```
return u"%s [%s]" % (self.name, self.get_gender_display())
```

Note, if you're not using Python 3+ you should be defining `__unicode__` rather than `__str__`.

Comment: can you explain the difference between unicode and str?  And should I define them both?

Comment: and in a template, you can use:
`{{ variable.get_fieldname_display }}`
HTH

Comment: In Python 3 you should be defining `__str__` rather than `__unicode__` though.