# Django enums visible within functions?

Tags: python, django, django-models, enums

In my model I've created an enun:

```
sc_goal_move_on = 0
sc_goal_cancel_project = 1
sc_goal_change_objectives = 2
sc_goal_other = 3

sc_review_goals = (
    (sc_goal_move_on, 'move_on'),
    (sc_goal_cancel_project, 'cancel_project'),
    (sc_goal_change_objectives, 'change_objectives'),
    (sc_goal_other, 'other')
)
```

And it's visible within classes when I define it as choises=

```
class project_phase(models.Model):
    phase = models.ForeignKey(phases)
    project = models.ForeignKey('project')
    date_start_plan_original = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    date_end_plan_original = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    is_closed = models.BooleanField()
    is_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_reviewed_by_pmo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phase_review_goal = models.IntegerField(choices=sc_review_goals, null=True)
```

But I can't access it from a model's def: to generate some HTML to make it available in my forms. Neither cs_review_goals or models.cs_review_goals work.

I guess I'm being silly and missing something simple here, please advise, thank you!

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761698/how-to-get-the-label-of-a-choice-in-a-django-choicefield), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105638/django-templates-verbose-version-of-a-choice) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962286/display-field-choice-as-part-of-model-string-name). Also, Python doesn't have _enums_; what you have is a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for access to `sc_review_goals` from within a class method?

It looks like it's a module level variable, so it should be accessible from a class method.

If you defined it within the class (as is suggested), you'd access it via `self.sc_review_goals` or `project_phase.sc_review_goals`.

Your problem may be that the variable name is `sc_review_goals` but you typed `cs_review_goals`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    A_VAR = 'var content'

    def a_method(self):
        print self.A_VAR # prints 'var content'
        print Student.A_VAR # also prints 'var content'
```