# Create alias for filtering ChoiceField in django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have following filterset for some model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    STATUS_ACTIVE = 0
    STATUS_DONE = 1
    STATUSES = (
        (STATUS_ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (STATUS_DONE, 'Done'),
    )

    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES, default=STATUS_ACTIVE)


class ModelFilter(FilterSet):
    status = ChoiceFilter(choices=MyModel.STATUSES)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'status',
        )
```

When I make request to some API, i should use status as number - `/app/model?status=0`.

How to make alias for it, so that i can use `/app/model?status=active` instead of number, without changing model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display field choice as part of model string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962286/display-field-choice-as-part-of-model-string-name)

Comment: This link probably doesn't exactly answer your question, but might provide a helpful tool to get you there. Django generates the `get_status_display()` function for your `status` model field that can probably be used for what you want.

Comment: Related [Return display_name in ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534239/return-display-name-in-choicefield?rq=1)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945327/django-rest-framework-with-choicefield

Comment: @Code-Apprentice none of these seem to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At th end I found source code inside the library and created this solution:

```py
class AliasesChoiceField(ChoiceField):
    def valid_value(self, value):
        for _, v in self.choices:
            if value == v or str(value) == str(v):
                return True
        return False

class AliasesChoiceFilter(ChoiceFilter):
    field_class = AliasesChoiceField
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        for val, alias in self.extra['choices']:
            if value == alias:
                return super(AliasesChoiceFilter, self).filter(qs, val)
        return super(AliasesChoiceFilter, self).filter(qs, value)
```

At `AliasesChoiceField.valid_value()` i just copied the base method with simple changes to validate value correctly.

`AliasesChoiceFilter` use `field_class` for validation, so i just replace it with `ChoiceFilter`, and change `filter()` method to right mapping of my choice parameters.

Finally my model looks like this

```py
class ModelFilter(FilterSet):
    STATUSES = (
        (MyModel.STATUS_ACTIVE, 'active'),
        (MyModel.STATUS_DONE, 'done')
    )
    status = AliasesChoiceFilter(choices=STATUSES)
```

And API route `/app/model?status=active` works correctly, setting right status on filtering.

But! This solution wouldn't work for Django Admin, or through web api interface, because it will offer real values, and will try to pass `0` instead of `active`